# Users redirected to staging slot during swap in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-deployment-slots

Today we experienced something curious and worrying during a swap from our staging deployment slot to our production deployment slot, and we are trying to understand how this could happen. Any insight would be most welcome.

We performed a 'regular swap' between our website's staging and production slots. Immediately after the swap completed two of our internal users experienced the following when attempting to access the URL configured for our production slot (both users were logged in at the time):

- they were logged out
- they were redirected to the login-page of the *staging* slot

We use forms-authentication, and the redirect-url in web.config is a relative URL.

This only happened to two users. When they tried to access the production URL a second time everything worked as expected.

Any ideas as to why/how this could happen?